# How to add extra columns to jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Does anyone know how to add extra columns in jQuery datatable? I have a jQuery datatable with five columns and I would like to add two extra columns.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table_vam" id="dt_gal">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table_checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="select_rows" class="select_rows" data-tableid="dt_gal" />
            </th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Start Price</th>
            <th>Reg Fee</th>
            <th>DateCreated</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="product" items="${PRODUCTS}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="row_sel" class="row_sel" />
                </td>
                <td>${product.productname}</td>
                <td>${product.code}</td>
                <td>${product.description}</td>
                <td>${product.startPrice}</td>
                <td>${product.registrationFee}</td>
                <td>${product.dateCreated}</td>
                <td><a href="${PREFIX}/product?edit=true&id=${product.id}" class="sepV_a" title='Edit'><i class='icon-pencil'></i>
                                            Edit </a> 
                    <!-- <a href="#" title='Delete'><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></td> -->
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I edited the block below, but it was not successful, as the table doesn't show from
`var iListLength = 5;` to `var iListLength = 7;`

```
    "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
        var iListLength = 5;
        var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
        var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
        var i, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);
```

Comment: Are you using a server-side or client-side datasource? Are the two columns you want to add part of the datasource or are they just arbitrary columns? Also, can you post your `dataTable` configuration section?

Comment: hi pete, its server side. Am using jquery.datatables.bootstrap.min.js, i have post sample above that is in a .jsp file.

Comment: Have you determined an acceptable solution for your question yet?

Comment: hi pete, yes..have posted the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the below in my datatable.js and now all added columns are visible.

Thanks

```
            oTable = $('#dt_e').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "sAjaxSource": "lib/datatables/server_side.php",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sClass": "center", "bSortable": false },
                **{ "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sWidth": "20%" },
                { "sWidth": "20%" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" },
                { "sClass": "center" }**

            ],
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
        } );
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not much a matter of jquery-datatables, and yes, html, since the result it will produce is the table structure you defined.

A column consists of

`th` = table header cell

`td` = cells

and line

`tr` = row

if your table looks like

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Field1</th>
   <th>Field2</th>
   <th>Field3</th>
   <th>Field4</th>
   <th>Field5</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>value1</td>
   <td>value2</td>
   <td>value3</td>
   <td>value4</td>
   <td>value5</td>
 </tr>
[...]
<table>
```

You will need to add 2 `<th>` for your column headers and 2 `<td>` for the fields

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Field1</th>
   <th>Field2</th>
   <th>Field3</th>
   <th>Field4</th>
   <th>Field5</th>
   <th>Field6</th>
   <th>Field7</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>value1</td>
   <td>value2</td>
   <td>value3</td>
   <td>value4</td>
   <td>value5</td>
   <td>value6</td>
   <td>value7</td>
 </tr>
[...]
<table>
```

Comment: Hi G.Mendes, i have done as above but still the table is not showing. I have added a sample in the questions. Thanks

Comment: @pmaingi I don't think the problem is in `fnUpdate` option, can you post the rest of the `datatable` config? Also note that you commented the `td` close each row on action rows